# How to find local network devices in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, node-modules, local-network

I need to find information (ip-address, mac-address etc) about local network devices in angular application

I have used package `local-devices` but it is producing issue, you may check here
[Can't resolve 'child_process' in 'node_modules\mz' in Angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53763572/module-not-found-with-local-devices-npm)

Is there any other package that can help me or help me in resolving issue with above mentioned package.

Please guide

Regards

Comment: Angular runs in a web browser and is limited to the security restrictions of a web browser. JavaScript source code can not touch the host machine. The NPM package you referenced is for NodeJS and not Angular.

Comment: so what would be the solution to find the local devices at client side?

Comment: Create a client that the user installs with desktop permissions.